# How can I be getting a NullReferenceException when using a type, not an object?

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xmlserializer

I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object") on the following call:

```
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooBar));
```

Here is `Foobar`:

```
class FooBar
{
    public int Alpha{ get; set; }
    public string[] Bravo{ get; set; }
    public int[] Charlie{ get; set; }    
    public List<int> Delta{ get; set; }
    //public List<int>[] Echo { get; set; }
}
```

The offending line is commented out. Un-comment it and I get the error at run-time. Left commented there is no error. XmlSerializer likes ints, int arrays, string arrays and lists of int, but seems to balk at arrays of lists of int. Any ideas why and/or a workaround?

Note: The cynic in me knows someone is going to try to step up and say "you haven't initialized any of the properties. That's why the null exception." In the actual program, they *are* initialized. But it doesn't matter if any of them are or are not initialized since I'm using `typeof`, not an instance.

Note 2: The experienced programmer in me is smelling a bug.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. That code (even **with** the line commented out) **will** throw an exception - but not the one you claim it will.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202994/how-to-xml-serialize-an-array-of-lists-of-objects may be worth a read. Found by Googling `xmlserialiser array of list nullreferenceexception`.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203601/106159) it looks like it's a bug in the serializer.

Comment: The responses here pretty much confirmed my suspicion (library bug) and suggested a work-around. A co-worker suggested List<List<int>> as Merhat Pandzharov did below.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int Alpha { get; set; }
    public string[] Bravo { get; set; }
    public int[] Charlie { get; set; }
    public List<int> Delta { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> Echo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give that one a try when I get home. An array of lists causes the exception. The shame is, apparently MS has known about it for at least 4 years now.